# Don´t display list if subcategory has only 1 item

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I´m displaying a menu with this code:

```
    <!--  Subcategory menu from current category -->
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <?php
        if (is_home()) {
            wp_list_categories('orderby=id&title_li=&depth=1');
        }
        else{
            $category = get_the_category();
            $cat_term_id = $category[0]->term_id;
            $cat_category_parent = $category[0]->category_parent;
            $listcat = wp_list_categories('echo=0&child_of='.$cat_category_parent.'&title_li=&orderby=order&order=ASC');
            $listcat = str_replace("cat-item-".$cat_term_id, "cat-item-".$cat_term_id." current-cat", $listcat);
            if ( in_category( $cat_term_id ) || post_is_in_descendant_category( $cat_term_id )) {
                echo $listcat;
            }
        }
    ?>
```

and each li of that menu display post titles using this:

```
    <!--  Post list from current category -->
    <div class="menu_list">
    <ul id="submenu_productos" class="clearfix">
        <?php
            $IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
            while( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();
                foreach( ( get_the_category() ) as $category )
                    $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=' . $category->category_nicename . '&orderby=date&order=DESC&showposts=100');
                if( $my_query ) {
                    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <!-- this line to hightlight current post in the category page -->
                <li<?php if ( $post->ID == $wp_query->post->ID ) { echo ' class="test"'; } else {} ?>>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </li>
        <?php
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

The menu works well and it shows like this:

[image]

The problem is that when I have one post that belongs to that category/subcategory it is also displayed on the list... I want to hide it when it´s only one item:

[image]

Is there any way to hide it when the subcategory has only one post?

PD: PLEASE avoid telling me to put this on wordpress.stackexchange.com, I always post there with no answer and here people always help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of item in your sub menu using :

```
$count = $my_query->post_count;
```

I'll suggest to add it in your if condition:

```
if( $my_query && $my_query->post_count > 1)
```

That should work